# How do I install xdebug extension for chrome or firefox Offline?

Tags: php, firefox, google-chrome-extension, xdebug

I am beginner in cakePhp I have two computer.  one which is connected to  the Internet I can debug but another which is not connected I can't debug

1. I install xdebug extension locally.
2. even I installed xdebug for chrome locally
   But I can't debug my website which is  a cakephp website 
   In php.ini configuration of x-debug section is:

   [X-Debug]
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
   zend_extension = D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll

All condition is the same between two computers  the only different is version of google one of them is which is connected to Internet is 79.0.3945.130 and another is 74......
with chrome I installed extension    but with fireFox I couldn't install edebug extension.

Can anybody help me how can I debug with vsCode locally?

Best Regards

Comment: You do not need extension to trigger debug. Just add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=YOUR_IDE_KEY_HERE` and it should work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point that I can debug cakePHP in vsCode offline is .vsCode folder in first level of cake site and inside it in launch.json file there is one line which is: "name": "Listen for XDebug", is the reason that you can debug in offline status,but how I have .vsCode folder I follow this link:
[Xdebu Installation Wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard)

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Other necessary step is  putting  the appropriate dll (php_xdebug-2.9.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll)  in this folder:
D:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.18\ext which is the extension folder of my active php